# Performance Issue while nineo_logical.log rotation - Windows 7

Tags: neo4j

While inserting data into my neo4j database via neo4jclient (rest) i noticed that there are times where no new nodes are created. This is when `messages.log` says there is a log rotation.

```
2014-09-03 09:24:24.727+0000 WARN  [o.n.k.EmbeddedGraphDatabase]: GC Monitor: Application threads blocked for an additional 103ms [total block time: 64.957s]
2014-09-03 09:25:05.303+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.t.x.XaLogicalLog]: Rotating [C:\PROGRA~1\NEO4J-~1.3-W\NEO4J-~1.3\data\graph.db\nioneo_logical.log.2] @ version=621 to C:\PROGRA~1\NEO4J-~1.3-W\NEO4J-~1.3\data\graph.db\nioneo_logical.log.1 from position 26214690
2014-09-03 09:25:05.303+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.t.x.XaLogicalLog]: Rotate log first start entry @ pos=25543534 out of [364439=Start[364439,xid=GlobalId[NEOKERNL|2191762550081260552|368202|-1], BranchId[ 52 49 52 49 52 49 ],master=-1,me=-1,time=2014-09-03 09:24:22.933+0000/1409736262933,lastCommittedTxWhenTransactionStarted=2098723], 364441=Start[364441,xid=GlobalId[NEOKERNL|-3264499367417003726|368203|-1], BranchId[ 52 49 52 49 52 49 ],master=-1,me=-1,time=2014-09-03 09:24:23.417+0000/1409736263417,lastCommittedTxWhenTransactionStarted=2098724]]
2014-09-03 09:25:05.475+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.t.x.XaLogicalLog]: Rotate: old log scanned, newLog @ pos=671172
2014-09-03 09:25:05.490+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.t.x.XaLogicalLog]: Log rotated, newLog @ pos=671172, version 622 and last tx 2098724
2014-09-03 09:25:22.744+0000 WARN  [o.n.k.EmbeddedGraphDatabase]: GC Monitor: Application threads blocked for an additional 103ms [total block time: 65.06s]
2014-09-03 09:26:33.694+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.t.x.XaLogicalLog]: Rotating [C:\PROGRA~1\NEO4J-~1.3-W\NEO4J-~1.3\data\graph.db\nioneo_logical.log.1] @ version=622 to C:\PROGRA~1\NEO4J-~1.3-W\NEO4J-~1.3\data\graph.db\nioneo_logical.log.2 from position 26215122
2014-09-03 09:26:33.694+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.t.x.XaLogicalLog]: Rotate log first start entry @ pos=26198480 out of [366049=Start[366049,xid=GlobalId[NEOKERNL|-4996649236013186268|369812|-1], BranchId[ 52 49 52 49 52 49 ],master=-1,me=-1,time=2014-09-03 09:25:51.558+0000/1409736351558,lastCommittedTxWhenTransactionStarted=2100333], 366051=Start[366051,xid=GlobalId[NEOKERNL|3341935111658490668|369813|-1], BranchId[ 52 49 52 49 52 49 ],master=-1,me=-1,time=2014-09-03 09:25:51.573+0000/1409736351573,lastCommittedTxWhenTransactionStarted=2100333]]
2014-09-03 09:26:33.710+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.t.x.XaLogicalLog]: Rotate: old log scanned, newLog @ pos=16658
2014-09-03 09:26:33.725+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.t.x.XaLogicalLog]: Log rotated, newLog @ pos=16658, version 623 and last tx 2100334
```

Because this is about once a minute and the rest api seems to be blocked this makes a really poor performance.

Is it possible and recommended to increase the log size? If I change the `keep_logical_logs=100M size` to something higher, does it effect this behaviour?

Any good tips to fasten the log rotation or avoid the rest blocking?

Comment: shoot from the hip: virus scanner? What kind of hardware HDD/SSD ?

Comment: Virus scanner deactivated ; hdd; the win7 system runs virtual on an esx host

Comment: virtualized environments are known for unpredictable IO latencies. Could you please try on a real hardware and see if the issue vanishes?